# Node - Error: Package subpath './public/extractFiles' is not defined by "exports" in

Tags: javascript, node.js

at sudden. I got this error

**UPDATe my question**

my npm version is 8.1.0
my node version 17

my tries to fix that issue

downgrade node version to 12, 14 , 16

none of them are fixed my issue

```
Error: Package subpath './public/extractFiles' is not defined by "exports" in /Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API/node_modules/extract-files/package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:416:9)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:669:3)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:482:36)
    at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:522:31)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
    at Function.wrappedResolveFilename [as _resolveFilename] (/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:364:42)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.wrappedLoad [as _load] (/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API/node_modules/newrelic/lib/shimmer.js:373:24)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "bds-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node-dev index.ts",
    "start-prod": "node dist/index.js",
    "start-prod-debug": "node --inspect dist/index.js",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "build": "npm run clean && npm run compile && npm run copy-graphql && npm run copy-newrelic",
    "compile": "ttsc",
    "clean": "rimraf dist/",
    "copy-graphql": "copyfiles \"lib/**/*.graphql\" dist/",
    "copy-newrelic": "copyfiles \"newrelic.js\" dist/",
    "testCI": "jest --ci --maxWorkers=2 --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --forceExit"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client": "^3.0.0",
    "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-types": "^2.2.0",
    "@sentry/apm": "^5.27.1",
    "@sentry/node": "^5.30.0",
    "@types/ws": "^7.4.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^4.6.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.874.0",
    "aws-xray-sdk": "^3.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "bottlejs": "^2.0.0",
    "case": "^1.6.2",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.5",
    "dataloader": "^2.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "fastify": "^3.14.1",
    "fastify-cors": "^5.2.0",
    "fastify-multipart": "^4.0.3",
    "fastify-websocket": "^3.1.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.6",
    "graphql": "15.5.0",
    "graphql-helix": "^1.2.3",
    "graphql-postgres-subscriptions": "^1.0.5",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "^1.2.1",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.11.0",
    "graphql-tools": "^7.0.4",
    "graphql-ws": "^4.3.1",
    "ioredis": "^4.24.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwk-to-pem": "^2.0.3",
    "knex": "^0.21.19",
    "luxon": "^1.26.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "newrelic": "^7.2.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "node-forge": "^0.10.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.5.0",
    "pg": "^8.5.1",
    "pg-listen": "^1.7.0",
    "pg-query-stream": "^4.0.0",
    "ramda": "^0.27.1",
    "request": "^2.88.2",
    "slonik": "^24.1.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/busboy": "^0.2.3",
    "@types/cheerio": "^0.22.28",
    "@types/glob": "^7.1.3",
    "@types/ioredis": "^4.22.1",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.22",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "@types/jwk-to-pem": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/luxon": "^1.26.2",
    "@types/mocha": "^8.2.2",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.5",
    "@types/newrelic": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.37",
    "@types/node-forge": "^0.9.7",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.1",
    "@types/pg": "^7.14.11",
    "@types/ramda": "0.27.32",
    "@types/request": "^2.48.4",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "copyfiles": "^2.4.1",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-junit": "^12.0.0",
    "jest-mock-extended": "^1.0.13",
    "mocha": "^8.3.2",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-auto-mock": "^2.7.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.5.4",
    "ts-mockito": "^2.6.1",
    "ts-node": "^9.1.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6",
    "ts-transformer-keys": "^0.4.3",
    "ttypescript": "^1.5.12",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  }
}
```

after deleting node_modules , package_lock.json

I got that error

```
# npm resolution error report

2021-11-23T15:32:18.364Z

While resolving: bds-api@1.0.0
Found: graphql@15.5.0
node_modules/graphql
  graphql@"15.5.0" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
peer graphql@"^0.10.5 || ^0.11.3 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0" from graphql-postgres-subscriptions@1.0.5
node_modules/graphql-postgres-subscriptions
  graphql-postgres-subscriptions@"^1.0.5" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "graphql",
    "version": "15.5.0",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "bds-api",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "path": "/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/graphql",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "graphql",
        "spec": "15.5.0",
        "from": {
          "location": "/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "graphql",
    "spec": "15.5.0",
    "from": {
      "location": "/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "graphql",
    "spec": "^0.10.5 || ^0.11.3 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "graphql-postgres-subscriptions",
      "version": "1.0.5",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "bds-api",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "path": "/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/graphql-postgres-subscriptions",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "graphql-postgres-subscriptions",
          "spec": "^1.0.5",
          "from": {
            "location": "/Users/minafawzy/Documents/TechModgroup/BDS-API"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

Comment: What's included this file ./public/extractFiles ?

Comment: extractFiles seems to be a dependency its under @graphql-tools

Comment: Please update your post and attach the file content for better helping

Comment: Thanks for reply but which file you want me to attach and where I can find it

Comment: The `exports` declarative of a package you are using is likely the problem. It specifies which parts may be imported/required, and what you use doesn't seem part of that package's public API.

Comment: Maybe package-lock.json and node_modules removing will fix your problem. suitable node version is latest LTS version.

Comment: I delete node_modules, package-lock.json and I got the error up

Comment: I think this is good solution. `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

What is npm version?

Comment: still the same issue I keep update my question to add more details